# Column username doesn't exist error when querying devise model with find_by_sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, devise

I'm trying to query my Devise-created table with find_by_sql and am running into a strange error.

```
User.find_by_sql("select username from user")
```

results in:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "username" does not exist
LINE 1: select username from user
: select username from user

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  
column "username" does not exist

LINE 1: select username from user
           ^
: select username from user
```

Here's my devise migration (I added the username field):

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :username,           null: false
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
  end
end
```

As you can see I have declared the field username. Querying other tables in this manner works perfectly. I have also tried `User.find_by_sql("select 'username' from user")`, and that just returns `[#<User id: nil>]`.

Thanks!

Edit: want to add that `User.last` returns

```
#<User id: 1, username: "xxxxxx", email: "xxxxxxxx", 
encrypted_password: "xxxxxx", reset_password_token: nil, 
reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, 
sign_in_count: 2, current_sign_in_at: "2016-06-26 20:16:59", 
last_sign_in_at: "2016-06-25 22:00:31", current_sign_in_ip: "xxxxx", 
last_sign_in_ip: "xxxx", created_at: "2016-06-25 22:00:31", 
updated_at: "2016-06-26 20:16:59">
```

with the correct values in place of 'xxxxx'

Comment: have you tried it using postgresql console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be because the name of the table is `users` rather than `user`. You can check `schema.rb` to check that the name of table is `users` or `user`. However, according to the migration, it has to be `users`.

This should work: `User.find_by_sql("select username from users")`. And you can use `User.find_by_sql("select id, username from users")` if you need user_id of record along with the username.

Or rather I would suggest you to do it in the ruby way: `User.select(:username)`

Hope it Helps : )

Comment: btw, make sure that you have run the migration and `users` table is present in schema.rb after migration.

Comment: Glad that it helped : )